# Importing LiDAR point cloud classes in Potree?

Tags: lidar, import, filter, las, potree

I can't find a way to import classes (roof, vegetation, ground, etc..) in Potree.

I generated the web page, except I get the black point cloud. When I, for example, open .las file in ERDAS Imagine, I get coloured points.

I tried to type these commands:

```
PotreeConverter /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter -o /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/output --output-attributes CLASSIFICATION --projection 4326 --generate-page MYPAGE

PotreeConverter /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter -o /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/output -a CLASSIFICATION --projection 4326 --generate-page MYPAGE

PotreeConverter /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter -o /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/output --output-attributes RGB CLASSIFICATION --projection 4326 --generate-page MYPAGE

PotreeConverter /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter -o /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/output -a RGB CLASSIFICATION --projection 4326 --generate-page MYPAGE

PotreeConverter /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter -o /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/output --projection 4326 --output-format LAS --generate-page MYPAGE
```

But all I get is black cloud point. I also tried to colour by height, but it's also black.

Answer (score 2):

I just uploaded a new version of LAStools today. Try running this via [laspublish](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/laspublish_README.txt) which is essentially just a wrapper for PotreeConverter but is tested to produce a functional Web portal.

Oh. And make sure your files are *not* in LAS 1.4 format which the PotreeConverter cannot yet handle. Maybe provide a lasinfo report ... ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Do you think this kind of report? https://www.sendspace.com/file/stfb8q
I added, also, a picture of my point cloud. 
My files are in las 1.2 formats. 
I will try with laspublish.